# Greasemonkey scripting. How to automatically click on a link that has unknown amount of white space in between

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, greasemonkey

I want a greasemonkey script that can automatically click on the a link that has specific words. In this case, I want the script to click on the link that says "Click Here To Accept!"  I found a script that works, however, the website I wanted to use it on has an abnormal link. It has unknown amount of white spaces between the word 'Here' and the word 'To'

```
<a
    href="accept.php?eSessID=7773160788107402312135408908242639440395021097128232706420140705121030&eSignupID=413&eEventID=102&sunow=1&ceRef=MOBILE"><b><u>Click Here
    To Accept!</u></b></a>
```

I found this script is seems to work on website that has a normal link. However, I suspect the script doesn't work on the above link because of the unknown amount of white spaces.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name Auto Click
// @version 1.0
// @author Joe
// @include  http://website.com/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/

//--- Note that the contains() text is case-sensitive.
var TargetLink = $("a:contains('Click Here To Accept!')")

if (TargetLink.length)
    window.location.href = TargetLink[0].href
```

I am a newbie at programming and have very limited knowledge in Javascripts. Please help me to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Scriptish you could use the simplified XPath function:

```
GM_xpath("//*[normalize-space()='Click Here To Accept!']//ancestor::a").click();
```

When you want to get a list of *all* occurrences use:

```
var myLinks = GM_xpath({path:"//*[normalize-space()='Click Here To Accept!']//ancestor::a", all:true});
```

and iterate over the returned links. Remember to `@grant GM_xpath` in the metadata header.

**Polyfill**
When the API of your userscript engine does not provide GM_xpath, you can implement it with `document.evaluate()`:

```
if(!this.GM_xpath)
  this.GM_xpath = function(descriptor)
  {
    if(descriptor === null || typeof descriptor === 'undefined')
      throw new TypeError('GM_xpath(): Descriptor must not be null or undefined.');

    var
      result, item, args,
      array = []
    ;

    args = descriptor.constructor.name === 'String'
      ? {path: descriptor, all:false}
      : {path: descriptor.path, all: descriptor.all}
    ;

    result = document.evaluate
    (
      args.path,
      document,
      document.createNSResolver(document),
      args.all ? XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE : XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE,
      null
    );

    if(!args.all)
      return result.singleNodeValue;

    while(item = result.iterateNext())
      array.push(item);
    return array;
  };
```

Comment: There is no `GM_xpath` in Greasemonkey. That's a ***Scriptish*** API.

Comment: @BrockAdams Many thanks for pointing that out! Furthermore there had been an error: The second form has to be passed as one argument as object. I've corrected the answer and added a polyfill.

Answer (score 1):

You can filter the links with a simple regex:

```
var targetLink = $("a").filter(function() {
    return /click\s+here\s+to\s+accept/i.test($(this).text());
});
```

Or you could go this way:

```
var targetLink = $("a:contains('Click'):contains('Here'):contains('To'):contains('Accept')");
```

But this will match even if the words aren't in the required order. I think the regex method is better.